# How to dynamically generate a string based on the provided variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Given the following fields:

```
Desk.red (true,false)
Desk.blue (true,false)
Desk.green (true,false)
Desk.purple (true,false)
Desk.orange (true,false)
```

Is it possible to create a helper method like so:

```
def desk_color_option_string(red,blue,green,purple,orange)
   sentence = "The desk is available in the color"
return sentence
```

Where given options like so:

```
(true, false, false, false, false)
(true, true, true, false, false)
(true, true, true, true, true)
```

The method returns

```
The desk is available in the color red.
The desk is available in the color red, blue, and green
The desk is available in the color red, blue, green, purple and orange.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the color names into an array, or pass in the array of colors, then use `to_sentence`:

```
def desk_color_option_string(red,blue,green,purple,orange)
  colors = method(__method__).parameters.map{ |arg| arg[1] if eval(arg[1].to_s)}.delete_if{ |arg| arg == nil}
  "The desk is available in the color #{colors.to_sentence}."
end
#=> The desk is available in the color red, blue and green.
```

Comment: That returned "true, true, true, and false"

Comment: Updated to get color names

Comment: Thanks but that now return "The desk is available in the color red, blue, green, purple, and orange." it seems to be thinking true or false is true. It should have returned "The desk is available in the colorS red, blue, and green"

Comment: Updated - removes colors that are false

Comment: please don't use `eval` but `public_send`.

Answer (score 0):

A good and totally dynamic way would be to use a hash. This way you dont need to remember the order of params. Also, having more than 2-3 params is a bad practice.

```
def desk_color_option_string(colors = {})
  "The desk is available in the color #{colors.select{|k,v|v}.keys.to_sentence}."
end
```

This will give you result according to the hash you will pass.

```
desk_color_option_string({red: true, blue: true, green: false})
#=> "The desk is available in the color red and blue."
```

or just pass the colors you want in string

```
desk_color_option_string({red: true, blue: true, green: true})
#=> "The desk is available in the color red, blue, and green."
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can generate a helper_method.

In **View**:

```
<p><%= desk_color_option_string(true, true, true, false, false) %></p>
```

In **Helper**:

```
def desk_color_option_string(red,blue,green,purple,orange)
   sentence = "The desk is available in the color " + method(__method__).parameters.map{|p| p[1] if eval(p[1].to_s)}.delete_if{|n| n==nil}.to_sentence
   return sentence
   # "The desk is available in the color red, blue and green"
end
```

Comment: That returned "true, true, true, and false"